# Reduce a fraction by interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Use $ x^2+1$ (polynomial interpolation) to reduce $$ \frac{(x^2+1)}{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}.$$

I don't know how I can reduce a fraction by interpolation method.

Comment: Well, neither do I. What does that mean? Thist fraction cannot be reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are to compute a third degree Lagrange interpolation polynomial with the roots $x=0,1,2,3$ of the denominator as sample points. That way you obtain the partial fraction decomposition of this rational function in a systematic way.